# Read out one Line for two variables but one is double and the other one is a string

Tags: c#

I wanted to read out two variables from one line, so I used var.
I encountered some difficulties with the second variable beeing a double and the first one beeing a string.

```
        var inputParts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        temp0 = inputParts[0];
        temp1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputParts[1]);
```

What's wrong with this type of code? Visual Studio didn't help me out there.
Thank you in forward :)

Comment: The two temp variables don't have any type declared. Besides that your code seems pretty fine.

Comment: They do, but not down there.
            string temp0;
            double temp1;

Comment: Can you be more specific with what kind of difficulties you're encountering? Are you getting compiler errors, runtime errors, unexpected behavior?

Also, using `var` does not change the type of a variable, it simply infers it from what's being assigned. Your `inputParts` variable here is of type `string[]`.

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't specific enough about the intire situation. I'm sorry, it's my first post after all.
So, we got this one line which should be read by the programm. This line can contain letter and numerics.
I simply want to split numbers from letters.

Comment: We don't know how your input looks like. Probably you will have problems with the comma or dot as the decimal separator. If you get exceptions you need to post this information. It is vital! And if you don't show the input we can guess here forever

Answer (score 0):

temp1 = double.Parse(inputParts[1]);

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? Presuming you're splitting based on a Space, I'd parse it as a String array. Check and see the type of the part first, before trying to convert to avoid exceptions.

```
string input = "x 3.3 z 2";

string[] cars = input.split(" ");

double x = double.TryParse(cars[1]);
```

If you are trying to just extract a double from a random string of input, you could use something like this:

```
string inputData = "sfdsdf2.2222sfdsfs";
var data = Regex.Match(inputData, "^(-?)(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\\.[0-9]+)?$").Value;
```

Comment: I'm currently using C# but I'm practicly pretty new to it and trying to learn. Never used arrays yet.

Comment: Didn't work out. It seems like the Problem simply is that there are also letters in the input.
Any idea how I make them "disappear" for the double variable?

Comment: @V.K.  You really need to show the input in the question, then.  Everyone's helping you solve the wrong problem, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that temp0 and temp1 do not have the right type.  For that code to work they should be defined as:

```
string temp0;
double temp1;
```

Edit: based on your comment below what you're actually getting is a run time exception because the string you're trying to parse does not match the expected format of a double.

You could print inputParts[1] to check what it actually contains.

If you're expecting your double to look like 1.0 (with a . for decimal separator) then you should do

```
temp1 = float.Parse(inputParts[1],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you don't use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture then the way that the double is parsed will depend on the user's locale.  The locale might be such that it expects a comma to be the decimal separator e.g. "1,0" so when it sees a '.' it will throw an exception.

Note that you will need to add

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: They are exactly that. Visual Studio just tells me that: "System.FormatException: "Die Eingabezeichenfolge hat das falsche Format.""
Which means it's not the right format

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete program that works:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                                        
public class Program
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                string temp0;
                double temp1;
                
                var inputParts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                
                temp0 = inputParts[0];
                temp1 = double.Parse(inputParts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The double was parsed as {0}", temp1));
        }
}
```

If you run this and enter input like

```
firstPartThatIsIgnored 100.5
```

You will get output

```
The double was parsed as 100.5
```